# Add to cart button not working - Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, magento

My 'add to cart' button has stopped working all of a sudden. I have no idea why because I haven't made any changes. I'm using **Magento version 1.7**.

Here's a link to my website - **http://www.bridalhotspot.co.uk/**.

When you click on 'add to cart', normally you would get the options 'continue shopping' or 'go to cart' but for some reason it now only gives the option 'continue shopping' without adding the product to the cart.

This is the code in my `addtocart.phtml` file:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo      

$this>getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>"   class="input-  text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
?>
```

---

**Edit:** I am receiving the following error in my console - `Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON"` when trying to add to cart.

```
Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON" prototype.js:1637
Ajax.Request.Class.create.getHeader prototype.js:1637
Ajax.Response.Class.create._getHeaderJSON prototype.js:1714
Ajax.Response.Class.create.initialize prototype.js:1675
klass prototype.js:101
Ajax.Request.Class.create.respondToReadyState prototype.js:1595
Ajax.Request.Class.create.onStateChange prototype.js:1545
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: Sorry I have no idea!
My website is http://www.bridalhotspot.co.uk

Comment: That makes all of us.

Comment: @Sylvana The error I get on your website is `"Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON" - prototype.js"`

Comment: @Sylvana It's to do with your AJAX. Are you sure no one has changed anything?

Comment: No, the only things I have been doing the last few days is adding or editing products through the magento admin panel

Comment: @Sylvana Do the comments here help? - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/219588/P30/#t337171

Comment: I turned off the secure url in admin as suggested but no change. Want you to know I'm very grateful for your help though!

Comment: @Sylvana No worries - Your base url is with the www. prefix yes?

Comment: @Sylvana Hmm, my advise would be to post this (including the error log I added to your question) to the Magneto forums - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards. I can't find that many solutions googling the error except for the things I just mentioned

Comment: I know what you mean, I have been Googling for hours before I posted this question here :( Will do so tomorrow! Many thanks for your help though, you're a star! xx

Comment: Is there any Javascript in `addtocart.phtml` besides `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)`? Also, are you using a common AJAX add to cart extension? If so, which one?

Comment: could you Please post the contents of the following file?

app/code/(local or community)/(Namespace)/ajaxcart cartcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enable "Use secure urls on frontend", look into System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Secure -> "Use secure urls on frontend"